# Sending bytes from javascript client to java backend DatagramSocket

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, datagram

I have a java app that functions as a server, listening to some port using the java.net.DatagramSocket class. The server is able to receive packets from some other java clients.
What I did not manage to do is have a javascript client to the server.
I've tried sending messages as WebSocket client

```
    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9999");
    ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
        console.log("CONNECTED")
    })
```

But I'm getting the following error in the browser console:

> App.js:9 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9999/' failed:

I've also tried using net library to send message:

```
    const net = require("net");
    const options = {
        post: 9999
    };
    const  client = net.createConnection(options);
    client.write("TEST")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: net.createConnection is not a function

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

UDP (DatagramSocket) and WebSocket are totally different things.
WebSocket is a protocol on top of HTTP which is on top of TCP.

In JavaScript running inside the browser you cannot send UDP packages.

You can write some kind of a proxy server, which can receive messages via WebSocket from your JavaScript program and send them via UDP to your server.

Or extend your server with a WebSocket interface.